GDB doesn't hit catchpoint on the child process forked off from debuggee
I was re-doing what described here about multiprocessing debugging in GDB.
The weird thing is that GDB doesn't hit the exec catchpoint on the child process running cat command (the latter is forked off from bash).
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo $$
670639
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/issue


root@ubuntu:~# gdb -q -p 670639
Attaching to process 670639
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/bash...
(No debugging symbols found in /usr/bin/bash)
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6...
(No debugging symbols found in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6)
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/49/0fef8403240c91833978d494d39e537409b92e.debug...
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/41/86944c50f8a32b47d74931e3f512b811813b64.debug...
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
pselect64_syscall (sigmask=0x564025a0c820 <_rl_orig_sigset>, timeout=<optimized out>, exceptfds=0x0, writefds=0x0, readfds=0x7ffe468736e0, nfds=1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pselect.c:34
34      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/pselect.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) catch fork
Catchpoint 1 (fork)
(gdb) catch exec 
Catchpoint 2 (exec)
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Catchpoint 1 (forked process 719946), arch_fork (ctid=0x7fbccdc6fa10) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arch-fork.h:52
52      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arch-fork.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) info inferiors 
  Num  Description       Connection           Executable        
* 1    process 670639    1 (native)           /usr/bin/bash     
(gdb) set detach-on-fork off
(gdb) nexti
[New inferior 2 (process 719946)]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
52      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arch-fork.h
(gdb) c
Continuing.

What is the reason behind it? Thanks.

Any comment/answer? Thanks.
